# Nested for-loop with lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested-for-loop

So I was trying to
(1) Use the vector function to create a list of size 3, name these as x,y,z
(2): Write a nested for loop, the outer loop iterating through the list (n=1:N), the inner from t=1:4
(3): Assign to the n−th list in each of the t−th positions in the vector, the value 10n+t

What I currently get is

```
N = 3
N_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = N) 
list_names <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
names(N_list) <- list_names
inner <- NULL
for (n in 1:N) {
    for (t in 1:4) {
        inner[[t]] <- t  
    }
    N_list[[n]] <- (10*n+inner[[t]]) 
}
```

Though I expect the list to be like:

```
$x  
[1] 11, 12, 13, 14  
$y    
[1] 21, 22, 23, 24  
$z  
[1] 31, 32, 33, 34
```

I actually only get 14, 24, 34 for each list.

Though I searched a lot of articles to learn about the logic of nested for-loop, I'm still not sure how to do it. Could somebody help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost correct. check this out:

```
N = 3
N_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = N) 
list_names <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
names(N_list) <- list_names

for (n in 1:N) {
    inner <- NULL # You should define inner here.
    for (t in 1:4) {
        inner[t] <- t  
    }
    N_list[[n]] <- (10 * n + inner) 
}

N_list
$x
[1] 11 12 13 14

$y
[1] 21 22 23 24

$z
[1] 31 32 33 34
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for sure, suppose the "inner" is used in the outer for-loop, should I define this "inner" before the whole for-loop code?

Comment: then it wont be changing as expected. You should not define it out of the outer loop.

Comment: Oh I got it thank you so much! Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow, will the question automatically be closed if I accept the solution? I cannot find the close button on the page.

Comment: Once the an answer is accepted, it shows that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one `for` loop :

```
N = 3
N_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = N) 
list_names <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
names(N_list) <- list_names
inner <- 1:4

for (n in 1:N) {
   N_list[[n]] <- (10*n+inner) 
}
N_list
#$x
#[1] 11 12 13 14

#$y
#[1] 21 22 23 24

#$z
#[1] 31 32 33 34
```

---

You can also use `lapply` :

```
lapply(seq_len(N), function(x) 10 * x + inner)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment!  lapply seems a better and simpler method in this case.